# Existence and Uniqueness for a state dependent piecewise ODE

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, dynamical-systems

I have the initial value problem 
$$\dot x(t) = h(t, x(t)), \quad x(t_0) = x_0$$
where $h$ has the form 
$$h(t, x)= \begin{cases} 
 h_2(t,x) & g(t,x) \geq 0 \\ 
 h_1(t,x) & \text{otherwise} \\ 
\end{cases}$$
where $h_1$ and $h_2$ are not necessarily equal. I want to state the necessary conditions on $h$ so that $x(t)$ is continuous on some interval $[t_0,t_1]$. I don't want to use the notion of a caratheodory or filippov solution, so I only want to use the regular existence and uniqueness theorem.

My claim is that sufficient conditions for $x(t)$ to be continuous are that: **1)** $h(t,x)$ is piecewise continuous on the interval $[t_0, t_1]$ and **2)** $ \partial h(t,x)/ \partial x$ is able to be bounded by a constant. 
My logic is that you can define the times $\theta_j, \ j = 0, \ldots, m$ such that on each interval $[\theta_j, \theta_{j+1}]$, $h(t,x)$ is continuous except at the endpoints ( and $[\theta_0, \theta_m] = [t_0, t_1]$) . Then starting on the first interval $[\theta_0, \theta_1]$ with the given initial condition, existence and uniqueness gives you $x(t)$ for $\theta_0 \leq t < \theta_1$ (where we assume that some region $\{(t,x): \ldots\}$ can be suitably chosen to guarantee existence on the whole interval). Then on the rest of the intervals $[\theta_{j}, \theta_{j+1}]$, you can take the initial condition to be 
$$\underset{\epsilon \rightarrow 0}{\lim} x(\theta_{j} - \epsilon)$$
and apply existence and uniqueness to get $x(t), \  \theta_j \leq t < \theta_{j+1}$. 
Then this shows that $x(t)$ is continuous on the entire interval $[t_0, t_1]$.

Do you think this proof is correct? Am I missing something? I just want $x(t)$ to be continuous on the whole interval.

Comment: Does your idea work for the simple example $g(x)=x$, $h_2=-1$, $h_1=1$? Or can you exclude it?

Comment: Well in this case I would say $h(t,x)$ is not piecewise since it will be switching arbitrarily fast, the number of discontinuities in $h(t,x)$ is not finite. But this is a good illustration of a possible problem, because to evaluate whether or not $h$ is piecewise, you already need $x(t)$, so then the condition $h(t,x)$ is piecewise seems circular in this regard. I'm not sure if you could make the conditions more precise based on this observation.

Comment: How did you get a quality "fast" for a static object like $h(t,x)$, which is a function on $\Bbb R^2$, and has only two constant pieces? Or do you pre-suppose the existence of a solution, to consider $t\mapsto h(t,x(t))$, to make up conditions on the existence of a solution?

Comment: I would define $x(t) = x_0 + \int_{t_0}^t h(t,x) dt$ as the solution on the first interval, then evaluate that until the $g$ condition is met, and call the time that happens $\theta_1$. Then I would keep doing that on the entire interval, specifying a $\theta_j$ everytime the $g$ condition is met/unmet. At the end of this process I would ask if the set of $\{ \theta_j \}$ is finite, and if it is then $h(t,x)$ can be regarded as piecewise continuous.

Comment: $h$ is a function, its properties are independent of any dynamic process defined with it. You can of course consider the solutions for $x'=h_1$ and $x'=h_2$ without regard to $g$, but if on $g=0$ you find that both solutions in time going forward lead only out of there domain as separated by $g$, then there is no solution. You wanted to codify this in terms of $g$ and $h$?

Comment: I agree your example doesn't have a solution and I want to state some sort of condition that excludes this type of situation.